# searching for Broadcom camera

Tags: command-line, drivers, broadcom, mac, camera

I have been searching, and searching how to search, and sometimes finding, but results are mixed and often accidental. I have a macbook air, and of course it has a Broadcom interface for wireless internet connection. Yeah, in searching for remedies I would find things but they always required to be online. I found an adapter for directly connecting my ethernet cable directly to a usb port. I have installed the workaround, so I am online now via my wi-fi. Accidental success.
The crux of my search now is to enable my built-in mac camera. It is a Broadcom unit. No surprise. How do I find the camera? A plain ls command is not fruitful. It does not reveal the camera, nor the Broadcom wireless network adapter. I did accidentally find a command sequence which *did* show me the wireless unit, and it was this: {sudo lshw -c network} and it displayed a bounty of information about the unit, so I know it can be found, if I just know the commands.
What command or commands are needed to lead me to the Broadcom camera?

Comment: I think you're looking for `lspci`, which will list all PCI-based devices. You may also want to check `lsusb`, which lists USB devices.

Comment: My camera appears in `lsusb`

Comment: lspci works to show me the camera, but lsusb did not reveal the camera